# Can a python builtin function be called using an object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, built-in

Am a newbie to Python. I have come across this code:

Xtrain is a pandas dataframe object with a shape of X train shape= (42000, 784)

But am able to call the python any() builtin function on the object returned by isnull function of a pandas dataframe

```
train = pd.read_csv(datapath+"/" +"train.csv")
X_train = train.drop(labels=["label"],axis=1)
X_train.isnull().any().describe()
```

I understood that builtin functions can be called directly from anywhere. Does the above mean that they are accessible to all objects also ? i.e. in some way every class inherits builtin functions  ?

Comment: That's not the `any` builtin. That's an unrelated method named `any`.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve.  `X_train.isnull()` will return a Dataframe with true/false for each **cell**. `X_train.isnull().describe()` will give you summary counts, number of unique value (probably 2, maybe 1) and top value with frequency.  Why do you want to use `any()`?

Comment: any in this case iis actually a function that is defined within the dataframe class definition, making it technically a method, it is not the same as the built in any function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments already address the question, but for the sake of posting a solution...

`builtin` functions can be called from anywhere, on anything - though whether or not they will work depends on whether or not you are passing in a valid input for that function.

`any` is a builtin function.

HOWEVER.. in this case, you are actually working with an `any` method that belongs to the `pd.DataFrame` class.

try `dir(pd.DataFrame)` ..  you will see `any` listed in there.

this means it's a function that belongs to the class (making it a method).

this is NOT the same as the `builtin any`.

Further proof...

```
import inspect

print(inspect.getfile(any))
```

output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\deden\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 666, in getfile
    type(object).__name__))
TypeError: module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object was expected, got builtin_function_or_method

print(inspect.getfile(pd.DataFrame.any))
```

output

```
C:\Users\deden\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py
```